# Php append to file if the string is unique

Tags: php, file, append

Is it possible to check if the string that is being added to file is not already in the file and only then add it? Right now I am using

```
        $myFile = "myFile.txt";
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
    $stringData = $var . "\n";
    fwrite($fh, $stringData);
    fclose($fh);
```

But I get many duplicates of $var values and wanted to get rid of them. 
Thank you

Comment: Can you more clarify the $var

Comment: More information would make this question easier to answer. Is the file always newline delimited? Are the string fixed-length? Is the file small (*feasible for `file_get_contents`*) or gargantuan?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this

```
$file = file_get_contents("myFile.txt");
if(strpos($file, $var) === false) {
   echo "String not found!";
   $myFile = "myFile.txt";
   $fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
   $stringData = $var . "\n";
   fwrite($fh, $stringData);
   fclose($fh);
}
```

Comment: +1 almost same time :)

Comment: what if the string found at position 0

Comment: @Akam, it can be solved with `strpos() === FALSE`

Comment: upvoting should only be for correct answer without any minor error :)

Answer (score 1):

Best way is use `file_get_contents` & perform operation only if $var is not in your file.

```
$myFile = "myFile.txt";
$file = file_get_contents($myFile);
if(strpos($file, $var) === FALSE) 
{
   $fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
   $stringData = $var . "\n";
   fwrite($fh, $stringData);
   fclose($fh);
}
```

Comment: `if(!strpos("some text", "some")){
echo "not found";
}` check this!

Answer (score 1):

```
$myFile = "myFile.txt";
$filecontent = file_get_contents($myFile);
if(strpos($filecontent, $var) === false){
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = $var . "\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);
}else{
 //string found
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution could be :

```
1. Fetch the contents using fread or file_get_contents
2. Compare the contents with the current contents in file
3. add it if it is not there.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function find_value($input) {

  $handle = @fopen("list.txt", "r");
   if ($handle) {
    while (!feof($handle)) {
     $entry_array = explode(":",fgets($handle));
     if ($entry_array[0] == $input) {
      return $entry_array[1];
     }
  }
 fclose($handle);
}
return NULL;
}
```

You can do the it like this also

```
$content = file_get_contents("titel.txt");
$newvalue = "word-searching";
//Then use strpos to find the text exist or not
```

Answer (score 0):

you could save all your added string in an array and the check with [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) if the current string has been added or not.

Second choice is to [read the file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) each time you want to write and do a [strstr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) on it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe **[fgets](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php)** is the answer here.

```
$handle = fopen($path, 'r+');      // open the file for r/w
while (!feof($handle)) {            // while not end
    $value = trim(fgets($handle)); // get the trimmed line
    if ($value == $input) {        // is it the value?
        return;                    // if so, bail out
    }                              //
}                                  // otherwise continue
fwrite($handle, $input);           // hasn't bailed, good to write
fclose($handle);                   // close the file
```

This answer is based solely on the fact that you have appended a newline (`"\n"`) in your code, which is why `fgets` will work here. This may be preferable over pulling the whole file into memory with `file_get_contents()`, simply because the size of the file may be prohibitive of that.

Alternatively, if the values are not newline delimited, but are fixed length, you can always use the `$length` argument of `fgets()` to pull exactly `$n` characters out (*or use `fread()` to pull exactly `$n` bytes out*)